# jQuery: fadeIn text input, stay visible until inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm basically trying it achieve is this: hovering over the `.header-logo` image, will fadeOut this image and fadeIn the `#header-search` text input field. The idea is that this `#header-search` field stays visible while it is active, i.e. you are typing in it, or fades out if you click elsewhere in the document. 
Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/2SNf6/ 
HTML:

```
<img class="header-logo" src="http://placekitten.com/160/50" />
<input id="header-search" type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.header-logo').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.header-logo').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        $('#header-search').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        });

    $('.#header-search').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#header-search').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        $('.header-logo').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        });    
});
```

Is this at all possible? I'm not sure how it would be achieved. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/2SNf6/1/

Comment: @adeneo perfect! cheers for that, put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Post it yourself, and accept it, gets you a few points !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a typo - replace .#header-search with #header-search. Also you dont need the stop method to make it work.

`$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.header-logo').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.header-logo').fadeOut();
    $('#header-search').fadeIn();
    });

$('#header-search').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#header-search').fadeOut();
    $('.header-logo').fadeIn();
    });
```

});`